# mysql access denied for 'root'@'name of the computer'

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am getting this error everytime im trying to connect to my database

```
    Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (28000/1045): 
Access denied for user 'root'@'name of the computer' (using password: YES) in PATH_TO_FILE on line 8
```

I checked the privilege and that's what I got

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'127.0.0.1' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

with that command

```
show GRANTS for "root"@"127.0.0.1"
```

Furthermore this is how i connect

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('path to server', 'root', 'gourami',"recherche");
```

but as you can see the name of the user is not the same in the error message...

I have no idea what is going on, because that should normally work..

I wonder if its my host that is blocked but I had that problem before,but the message wasn't the same. I fixed it with the command.

```
flush hosts;
```

But this time it didn't work

The database is in another server, before everything was working but now for some reason I cant connect.

Answer (score 1):

If your "Access denied" message states 'root'@'name of the computer'... then you probably need to grant access to 'root'@'IP address of the computer'.

Comment: I give it a try, it didn't give me any error..but it still didn't work

Comment: Assuming you are providing the right password. What's the IP address that 'name of the computer' resolves to? Maybe your box is setup such that you are connecting to mysql from the IP address of the box instead of localhost, try that.

Comment: I am connecting from the IP address since it's mysql another server.

Comment: did you grant 'root'@'ip address of your computer' ?

Comment: It creates an error
`Error code: 1133. Can't find match any matching row in the table`

Comment: Your main problem is that root does not have privilege of remote access. Check if this is of any help as you are facing error in `GRANT`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101789/error-1133-when-creating-users-in-sql-script

Comment: I already tried it..

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a user who is not root to your database. Connecting your PHP script to the database using root is probably not a great idea.

`grant some permissions on webDB.* to webUser identified by 'really_good_password'`

to see what permissions your webUser will need, check the MySQL docs http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html#grant-database-privileges

That way you limit the damage someone can do if they get hold of the account details for your webUser

Comment: So true... if indeed the OP is trying to connect for non-administrator reasons then that's a very very necessary step.

Comment: I tried that, and for some reason now it's says
`(using password: NO)` instead of `(using password: YES)`
although I put the password..but it still doesn't work

Comment: Can you post up your connection string or the command you are entering? 
From the command line `mysql -u webUser -p` should then prompt you for the password you entered when you added them

Comment: Yes its already on top

Comment: Can you connect from the command line as webUser when you are on the server?
Did you `flush privileges` after adding the user?

Comment: I cant use the command line for some reason ... When i created a user I did it on the workbench,by going in manage security

Comment: OK. Does workbench allow you to log in as the user you created?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8388/discussion-between-komlan-and-steve-n)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `Host`, `User` FROM `mysql`.`user`;
```

This will display the current hosts which each MySQL user can login from. If you need access from any host, it should be updated to `%`, though strictly not recommended for production servers. In order to access from a server whose IP address is known to you, its IP address should be there in the Host column.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I already went there... I also created another user but even with all this it still doesn't work..